# Dúvida sobre laços de repetição em C

Tags: c, loop, for, lógica

Estou tentando resolver essa questão:

**3. O usuário digita dois números x e y (com x < y):

(b) O programa retorna a soma dos números perfeitos do intervalo [x, y].**

Porém, ele me retorna o número 2.
O caso de teste que estou usando é 0 a 10, ou seja, `printf("Item b = %d", q3b(0,10))`. Onde posso estar errando?

```
int q3b (int x, int y){
    int i, j, somaparcial = 0, somatotal = 0; 

    for (i = x; i <= y; i++){
        for(j = 1; j < i; j++){
            if(i==0 || i%j == 0){
                somaparcial = somaparcial + i;
            }
            
            if( somaparcial == i){
                somatotal = somatotal + i;
            }
        }
    }
    return somatotal;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Olhando superficialmente.

Você está errando nessa linha:

```
somaparcial = somaparcial + i;
```

Que deveria ser:

```
somaparcial = somaparcial + j;
```

E também está errando no bloco:

```
for (i = x; i <= y; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < i; j++){
        if(i==0 || i%j == 0){
            somaparcial = somaparcial + j;
        }
        
        if( somaparcial == i){
            somatotal = somatotal + i;
        }
    }
}
```

A variável `somaparcial` deveria ser zerada a cada iteração de `i`:

```
somaparcial = 0
```

Onde a condição:

```
if( somaparcial == i){
    somatotal = somatotal + i;
}
```

Deveria estar localizada um escopo acima:

```
for (i = x; i <= y; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < i; j++){
        if(i==0 || i%j == 0){
            somaparcial = somaparcial + j;
        }
    }
    if( somaparcial == i){
        somatotal = somatotal + i;
    }        
}
```

O que aplicando as correções ao código apresentado na questão:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int q3b (int x, int y){
    int i, j, somaparcial = 0, somatotal = 0; 

    for (i = x; i <= y; i++){
        somaparcial = 0;
        for(j = 1; j < i; j++){
            if(i%j == 0){
                somaparcial = somaparcial + j;
            }
        }
        if(somaparcial == i){
            somatotal = somatotal + i;
        }
    }
    return somatotal;
}

int main(void) {
  printf ("Item b = %d",q3b(0, 10));
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Perfeitos2#main.c)</sup>

## Um olhar mais aprofundado.

[Números perfeitos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_perfeito) são números naturais para o qual a soma de todos os seus divisores naturais próprios (excluindo ele mesmo) é igual ao próprio número. A [Fundação OEIS](http://oeisf.org/) possui em seu catalogo uma [sequencia dos números perfeitos](https://oeis.org/A000396).

Conhecendo a definição de número perfeito e sabendo que o problema consiste em obter a soma de todos os números perfeitos dentro de intervalo então seu problema se define em:

- iterar por um determinado intervalo de números naturais.
- encontrar os números perfeitos deste intervalo.
- soma os números perfeitos encontrados.

Então para iterar por um intervalo números naturais e levando em conta a magnitude dos números elencados na sequência de números perfeitos, devemos assegurar o domínio cujo trabalharemos mudando tipo das variáveis de `int` e passando para `unsigned long long`, ou seja deixamos de trabalhar com um inteiro de 32 bits cujo o domínio está na faixa de `[-2147483648, +2147483647]` para usar um natural de 64 bits na cujo o domínio está na faixa de `[0, +18446744073709551615]` o suficiente para trabalhar com os oito primeiros números perfeitos.

É sempre bom ao escrever uma função estabelecer salvaguardas para caso o usuário entre com valores indevidos na função. Neste caso em específico o enunciado do exercício exige que o parâmetro `x` seja menor que o parâmetro `y` implicando na adição da salvaguarda:

```
if (y < x) return 0;
```

Ou seja a função retorna `0` caso o usuário não respeite a regra de que o parâmetro `x` seja menor que o parâmetro `y`.

É importante é usar nomes compreensíveis e bem legíveis para identificadores. No caso específico mudei a assinatura da função de:

```
int q3b (int x, int y)
```

Para:

```
unsigned long long soma_perfeitos(
    unsigned long long inicio,       /* inicio do intervalo de operação da função. */
    unsigned long long fim           /* fim do intervalo de operação da função. */
)
```

Também clarifique os identificadores de variáveis e passe suas declaração para dentro dos respectivos escopos de ação.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
 *  A função soma_perfeitos realiza e retorna a soma do
 *  números naturais contidos no intervalo [inicio. fim]
 *  tal que inicio e fim sejam naturais menores que 18446744073709551615
 *  e que inicio anteceda fim.
 */
unsigned long long soma_perfeitos(
    unsigned long long inicio,       /* inicio do intervalo de operação da função. */
    unsigned long long fim           /* fim do intervalo de operação da função. */
){
    if (fim < inicio) return 0;            /* caso o intervalo de operação da função seja contraditório retorna 0. */
    unsigned long long total = 0;           /* Inicializa a variável que irá totalizar a soma dos números do números perfeitos */
    for (unsigned long long i = inicio; i <= fim; i++){    /* itera em i pelo intervalo que vai de inicio até fim... */
        unsigned long long somaDivisores = 0;              /** ...inicializa a variável que irá guardar a soma dos números de i. **/
        for(unsigned long long j = 1; j < i; j++){         /** ...itera em j pelo intervalo que vai de 1 até i...**/  
            if(i%j == 0){                  /** ... se j for um divisor de i...**/
                somaDivisores += j;        /*** ... soma j a soma dos divisores de i. ***/
            }
        }
        if(somaDivisores == i){            /** ...se i for um número perfeito...**/
            total += i;                    /*** ... adiciona i ao total dos números do números perfeitos. ***/
        }        
    }
    return total;                          /* retorna o resultado da função. */   
}

int main(){
  printf ("Item b = %llu", soma_perfeitos(0,2305));
}
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Perfeitos#main.c)</sup>